# MVC Analytics helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-analytics

Google has multiple options to generate ag code script depends on what you tracking:

```
1)A single domain e.g site.com
2)One domain with multiple subdomains e.g site.com/something.site.com
3)Multiple top-level domains e.g site.ch/site.fr
```

but `Microsoft.Web.Helpers` has only two google methods:

```
GetGoogleAsyncHtml(string webPropertyId);
GetGoogleHtml(string webPropertyId);
```

So there is no way to control options i described above.

Is it big deal if i would have site with `One domain with multiple subdomains(second options)` but at the same time i would use one of methods above, or better just to get script form google in such case and forgot about that helper?

p.s.
I just find out that method `@Analytics.GetGoogleAsyncHtml()` returns exactly the same ga script as google `A single domain e.g site.com` does. So looks like that helper does not generate another two types.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own helper that will do the job that you want. This is what i have done on my side to support [Piwik](http://piwik.org). Just take the following example and edit it to support what you want for Google Analytics.

```
public class Analytics : HelperPage
{
    public static HelperResult GetPiwikHtml(Uri serverHost, int siteId)
    {
        string host = serverHost.Host;

        return new HelperResult(x =>
        {
            HelperPage.WriteLiteralTo(x, "    <!-- Piwik -->\r\n");
            HelperPage.WriteLiteralTo(x, "    <script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n        var pkBaseURL = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ? \"https://" + host + "/\" : \"http://" + host + "/\");\r\n        document.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src='\" + pkBaseURL + \"piwik.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E\"));\r\n    </script>\r\n");
            HelperPage.WriteLiteralTo(x, "    <script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n        try{\r\n            var piwikTracker = Piwik.getTracker(pkBaseURL + \"piwik.php\", ");
            HelperPage.WriteTo(x, siteId);
            HelperPage.WriteLiteralTo(x, ");\r\n            piwikTracker.trackPageView();\r\n            piwikTracker.enableLinkTracking();\r\n        } catch(err) {}\r\n    </script>\r\n");
            HelperPage.WriteLiteralTo(x, "    <noscript><p><img src=\"http://" + host + "/piwik.php?idsite=" + siteId + "\" style=\"border:0\" alt=\"\" /></p></noscript>\r\n");
            HelperPage.WriteLiteralTo(x, "    <!-- End Piwik Tracking Code -->");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is my solution working for you? if not, please tell what is not working here so i can help you more.